# Java: got an unexpected output

Tags: java

I'am learning Java and I got an unexpected output. That's the code:

```
public class Point {
    protected final int x,y;
    private final String name;

    public Point(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        name = makeName();
    }

    protected String makeName() {

        return "["+x+" ,"+y+"]";
    }
    public final String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
public class ColorPoint extends Point{
    private final String color;

    public ColorPoint(int x,int y, String color){
        super(x,y);
        this.color = color;
    }

    protected String makeName(){
        return super.makeName() + ":" + color;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(
                new ColorPoint(4,2,"viola"));
    }
}
```

The output is: `[4,2]:null`.
Why? Shouldn't it be just `[4,2]` because the variable String name is initialized first in `makeName()` method of the `Point` class and then should become unmutable? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `makeName()` method is called before you set `this.color = color`;

The `makeName()` method is called by your super.construtctor when the color variable is still `null`.

Comment: so the makeName() method called is the method of ColorPoint class ?

Comment: yes.  the `makeName` method in `ColorPoint` overrides the super method, and you are calling `colorPoint.makeName()`;

Answer (score 0):

super(x,y) is calling method makeName() of ColorPoint class and color is not assigned till then.

Answer (score 0):

Flow is like this,

```
Point constructor > makeName of ColorPoint > makeName of Point
```

since, makeName of ColorPoint is called first, till that time color property value was not assigned, so its giving null

Answer (score 0):

`makeName()` is called in the constructor of the superclass.
When it is called color is not yet set so the default value of color is null.

To solve the problem you have to explicitly call `makeName()` at the end of constructor. Here is the correct code:

```
public ColorPoint(int x,int y, String color){
    super(x,y);
    this.color = color;
    makeName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new ColorPoint(4,2,"viola"));
```

calls the constructor on line 22 , which inturn calls the constructor on line 5
the constructor on line 5 calls the overridden function make name on line 27
which sets name as [4,2]:null because colour hasnt been initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

`final` fields are initialized with default values (which for references is `null`). You can easily check it with this code:

```
class FinalTest{
    public final String value = test();

    private String test() {
        System.out.println("current state of value is '"+value+"'");
        return "foo";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalTest ft = new FinalTest();
        System.out.println(ft.value);
    }
}
```

which produces output:

```
current state of value is 'null'
foo
```

So as you see final variable has its default value which can be later modified in constructor once.

But lets get back to your example. When you call

```
System.out.println(new ColorPoint(4, 2, "viola"));
```

you are creating invoking constructor of `ColorPoint` class, and then on this instance `toString` will be called. But lets take a closer look at `ColorPoint` constructor:

```
public ColorPoint(int x, int y, String color) {
    super(x, y);
    this.color = color;
}
```

As you see before `this.color` will be set you are invoking `super(x,y)` which code looks like this:

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    name = makeName();
}
```

But here in `makeName();` thanks to polymorphism ([late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java)) you are using code of `makeName` from `ColorPoint` class which looks like

```
protected String makeName() {
    return super.makeName() + ":" + color;
}
```

So at start you will get result of `super.makeName()` which is `"[" + x + " ," + y + "]"` but then you are trying to access `color` which as you remember is not initialized with because

```
super(x, y); //<-- we are still here
this.color = color;//this wasn't invoked (yet)
```

so `color` still has its default value (`null`).

This means that `name` will be set to `[4 ,2]:null`.

Since `ColorPoint` inherits `toString` from `Point` which looks like

```
public final String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

you see as output value stored in `name` which is `[4 ,2]:null`.